How to reset ESP32 board
I'm a beginner with the wESP32 board from Silcognition (https://wesp32.com/). My problem is that I can upload a program only once and then the board won't accept another program. I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows with the Platformio IDE and the Arduino platform. The first program (a wifi scanner) loads and runs just fine but subsequent attempts end with a serial port communication error. Yes, Windows and the IDE can find the port (COM5 on my machine), and yes the serial monitor has no problem reading input from the wESP32 on that same port (baud = 115200). What am I doing wrong?
I've tried using a different platform (Expressif IDE) with the same result. I've also tried specifying the COM port and the baud rate (9600) in the platformio.ini file. No luck.
